# How to get elements only until next (the same) tag?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have HTML file that includes something like that:

```
<h1>AAA</h1>
   <h2>part1</h2>  
     <ul>
       <li>ap1-1</li>
       <li>ap1-2</li>
     </ul>
   <h2>part2</h2>
     <ul>
       <li>ap2-1</li>
       <li>ap2-2</li>
     </ul>

<h1>BBB</h1>
   <h2>part1</h2>  
     <ul>
       <li>bp1-1</li>
       <li>bp1-2</li>
     </ul>
   <h2>part2</h2>
     <ul>
       <li>bp2-1</li>
       <li>bp2-2</li>
    </ul>
```

"part1" and "part2" may be absent or have exchanged positions.

And I want to get next list:

```
  <ul>
       <li>ap2-1</li>
       <li>ap2-2</li>
  </ul>
```

I try to use select query something like

```
document.select("h1:contains(AAA) ~ h2:contains(part2) + ul > li")
```

but the result also includes items from BBB - part: "bp2-1" and "bp2-2".
How can I avoid BBB-part items?

Comment: h1 is a complete/closed tag with no contents, instead select `ul`

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul id="ul">
       <li>bp1-1</li>
       <li>bp1-2</li>
</ul>
```

- 

```
document.getElementById("ul").innerHTML
```

A resource on getElementById():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById